# Need to select most recent record, group by customer and item code

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a basic order detail table that contains: `docDate`, `customerCode`, `itemCode`, `Price`, and `Quantity`. Looked through a number of similar questions, but they didn't seem to take into account everything I need, and I failed to re-purpose the other solutions.

The end goal: Only the most recent record of each individual item ever bought by a customer. (So one record per item)

Prices and quantities change record to record, and I just want the most recent.

This provides me with the most recent entry of each Item (code and date)

```
SELECT itemCode, MAX(docDate) AS docDate
FROM RDR1 
WHERE customerCode= 'TEST001' 
GROUP BY ItemCode
```

Now I need to be able to pull the other pieces of information from those most recent rows, like price and quantity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to something like this:

```
   select
    * -- or whatever columns you actually want
    from
    RDR1
    inner join
    (SELECT itemCode, MAX(docDate) AS docDate
    FROM RDR1 
    WHERE customerCode= 'TEST001' 
    GROUP BY ItemCode) MD
    on MD.docDate = RDR1.docDate
and md.ItemCode = RDR1.ItemCode
```

Comment: Okay so this is almost it. There also needs to be another WHERE customerCode = 'TEST001' outside of the subquery, because it is pulling orders from other customers that also ordered that product on the same date.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT distinct (ItemCode), docDate, Price, Quantity
FROM RDR1
WHERE customerCode= 'TEST001' 
ORDER BY docDate DESC
```

Comment: This creates a record for every different price and quantity. I'm looking for the most recent entry for each item code, regardless of quantity or price.  So if item 5 cases of item A were sold on an order today @ $10/case , and 10 cases of item A were sold on an order yesterday @ $15/case, I would only see one record of Case A with a quantity of 5 and a price of $10

Comment: Nope. The OP only wants to see data for the most recent row for each item.

Answer (score 0):

Using [ROW_NUMBER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY itemCode ORDER BY docDate DESC) AS RowNumber, *
    FROM RDR1
    WHERE customerCode = 'TEST001'
) x
WHERE x.RowNumber = 1
ORDER BY x.itemCode
```

For an overview of multiple customers, add `customerCode` to the partition:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customerCode, itemCode ORDER BY docDate DESC) AS RowNumber, *
```