# Return rows with column having min value

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a scenario

```
Key Name Amt
101 Nikh 100
101 Mark 150
101 Jess 75
102 Sam  200
102 Lee  150
```

Observe that Key is same for multiple records. Also it is coming from a different table than Name and Amt. I want to returns records havig minimum Amt. Below is the eg.:

```
Key  Name  Amt
101  Jess  75
102  Lee   150
```

So far, I have a code running which returns the Key and Amt records, How do I add a Name column and make sure it returns exactly the name associated with the min(Amt)
Pl note: I am working on SSRS 2008.

For better understanding, I am pasting my code here(edited):

```
SELECT       A.AppID,A.AppDetailID, MIN(B.Amt) AS LOWAmt
FROM         AppDetail AS A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT        TOP (100) PERCENT C.AppID, C.PartyID, MIN(C.TotalScore) AS Amt, D.Name, D.Indicator, E.FirstName, E.LastName
     FROM       DetailGuarantor AS D RIGHT OUTER JOIN
     Applicant AS E ON D.BeginDate = E.BeginDate AND 
     D.PartyID = E.PartyID AND 
     D.AppID = E.AppID RIGHT OUTER JOIN
     ApplicationScore AS C ON 
     E.AppID = C.AppID AND 
     E.PartyID = C.PartyID
     GROUP BY C.AppID, C.PartyID, D.Name, D.Indicator, E.FirstName, E.LastName, 
     ORDER BY C.AppID, Amt) AS B ON A.AppID = B.AppID 

GROUP BY A.AppID,A.AppDetailID
```

Comment: Similar to [this recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24270762/1578604), with the difference that you are looking for MIN instead of MAX.

Comment: You mean the tables A, B, C, D, E are view tables, then Yes

Comment: Apologize for misinterpreting your question. No, it's not a view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should approach this using `row_number()`:

```
select [key], name, amt
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by [key] order by amt asc) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: I have a very complex code where this is just a small part of it. The Key column table is the main table from which there are atleast 10 tables which are joined using left outer join (sub queries). Name and amt is another table. Even in that amt is not a straight forward column. In that case, how do I incorporate this code. It seems to be very useful.

Comment: @Anon: Can you please elaborate on what you mean by' What about ties'?

Comment: If your data also had `102 Fred 150`, what would your desired output be?

Comment: Won't have a name with same amt for sure

Answer (score 3):

Classic question and answer

```
;WITH CTE as
(
  SELECT row_number() over (partition by  [Key] order by Amt) rn, 
    [Key],
    Name,
    Amt
  FROM <table>
)
SELECT [Key], Name, Amt
FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 1
```

Edit: If, in case of ties, you want to show all results with the lowest Amt, replace `row_number()` with `rank()`

Answer (score 0):

If you want just a simple query, then here's a way to do this:

```
SELECT       Tab.KeyID, Tab.Name, Tab.Amt
FROM         Tab
INNER JOIN  (SELECT     MIN(Amt) as 'minAmt', [KeyID]
             FROM       Tab
             GROUP BY   [KeyID]) lowestAmt

ON           Tab.KeyID = lowestAmt.KeyID

WHERE        Tab.Amt = lowestAmt.minAmt
GROUP BY     Tab.KeyID, Tab.Name, Tab.Amt
ORDER BY     Tab.KeyID
```

You can see this here-> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b2628/39

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: I don't see this as being similar to what the OP wants as output?

Comment: Jerry - You should read/learn about ranking functions. They will really make your life easier. You will thank me later

Comment: @t-clausen.dk I realize I made a mistake. Thanks. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk Do you see anything wrong with this now?

Comment: you are forcing a 'with ties', your script is not easy readable. Your performance will not be optimal

Comment: @t-clausen.dk Firstly, as far as the OP's question is concerned, the comment "Won't have a name with same amt for sure" (see the comment on Gordon Linoff's answer) answers the "with ties" condition. **If you read & understand that statement correctly, the scenario "with ties" won't arise in this case.**

Comment: @t-clausen.dk Secondly, "your script is not easy readable" is **YOUR OPINION** not a fact!! You are just trying to make it sound like some universal fact. On the other hand, **its just a simple query with an inner join on the same table, what's so un-readable about it?**

Comment: @t-clausen.dk Thirdly, you state "Your performance will not be optimal" without stating any reason as to why. Why not optimal? Does it create any bottlenecks? What exactly is the bottleneck? The fact that you provide no justifiable reason for that statement makes it lose its very credibility. In other words, "Your performance will not be optimal" is again just that: **YOUR OPINION!!!**

Comment: @SatwikNadkarny making subqueries is slower than ranking functions, performance is not up for negotiation. So it does make bottlenecks. Do you know what 'with ties' means at all ? It means rows with the buttom(or top) value will be shown. This cannot be disabled in this query, so yes indeed it is forced. So it is not my opinion, it is facts

Comment: @Satwiknadkarny: Can you please check my edited question? My code is much complex and hence not sure where I can incorporate your query.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk "making subqueries is slower than ranking functions, performance is not up for negotiation". You are making a **blanket statement**. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232470/performance-rank-vs-sub-query-sub-query-have-lower-cost. That statement is not **necessarily** true. In case you don't understand the meaning of that post, it means *performance depends on a lot of factors* due to which it cannot be sufficiently established as to which performs better.In light of this, your aforementioned statement is just that: **YOUR OPINION**

Comment: @t-clausen.dk In case you disagree, and still believe that ranking functions and subqueries is always and always *like Michael Schumacher in front of Lucas Badoer*, kindly feel free to do us all a favour by proving that point with benchmarking results.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk "Do you know what 'with ties' means at all ? It means rows with the buttom(or top) value will be shown". *Not part of the OP's question*. That seems to be your concern, not OP's. I was trying to answer according to his/her concerns, not yours. Get that? Besides, the OP **clearly states** such a scenario is not possible so I can't fathom why you'd keeping shoving that point again and again.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk "So it is not my opinion, it is facts". So, is "your script is not easy readable" a FACT?